# Within-cell operations in matching R data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two matching data frames in R, one has strings separated by underscores and the other has matching counts for the strings also separated by underscores. Here are some excerpts:

strings_df:

```
SampleName  V1  V2
asd A/I/R   S/G
asd A/I/R   NA
afsdf   A/I/R_A/I/R_V/I/R   S/G_A/A_C/A_F/A
dsg A/I/R   S/G
eee A/I/R   S/G
shg NA  NA
gfdf    A/I/R_A/I/R_A/I/R   NA
```

counts_df:

```
SampleName  V1  V2
asd 53  35
asd 66  NA
afsdf   78_80_100   66_55_30
dsg 99  65
eee 64  43
shg NA  NA
gfdf    46/47/88    NA
```

Whenever there are two identical strings in strings_df (such as A/I/R in A/I/R_A/I/R_V/I/R) I need to sum the corresponding counts in counts_df and only leave a single instance of the string in strings_df, otherwise data should be left as is.

The output data frames for this example would be:

resulting_strings_df:

```
SampleName  V1  V2
asd A/I/R   S/G
asd A/I/R   NA
afsdf   A/I/R_V/I/R S/G_A/A_C/A_F/A
dsg A/I/R   S/G
eee A/I/R   S/G
shg NA  NA
gfdf    A/I/R   NA
```

resulting_counts_df:

```
SampleName  V1  V2
asd 53  35
asd 66  NA
afsdf   158_100 66_55_30
dsg 99  65
eee 64  43
shg NA  NA
gfdf    181 NA
```

I've tried separating the columns with separate() using the underscore as separator but because the number of underscores on cells is uneven, it ends up being a total mess. I'm stuck at that point at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach with `dplyr`, assuming rows between the datasets correspond.

First combine the data after renaming the columns, then detect duplicates and sum/paste respectively.

```
library(dplyr)

df_new <- tibble(strings_df %>% rename_with(function(x) paste0(x, ".X")), 
                 counts_df %>% rename_with(function(x) paste0(x, ".Y"))) %>% 
  mutate(spli = Vectorize(\(x) as.numeric(x))(strsplit(V1.Y, "_|/")), 
         spli_chr = ifelse(lengths(spli) > 1, strsplit(V1.X, "_"), V1.X)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(is = list(duplicated(spli_chr) | duplicated(spli_chr, fromLast=T)), 
         spli = paste0(sum(spli[is]), "_", spli[!is]), 
         V1.X = paste(unique(spli_chr), collapse="_"), 
         V1.Y = gsub("^_|0_|_0|_$", "", spli)) %>% 
  select(-c(spli, spli_chr, is)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Get the single data sets after regaining the original colnames.

```
df_new %>% 
  select(ends_with(".X")) %>% 
  rename_with(function(x) colnames(strings_df))
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  SampleName V1          V2             
  <chr>      <chr>       <chr>          
1 asd        A/I/R       S/G            
2 asd        A/I/R       NA             
3 afsdf      A/I/R_V/I/R S/G_A/A_C/A_F/A
4 dsg        A/I/R       S/G            
5 eee        A/I/R       S/G            
6 shg        NA          NA             
7 gfdf       A/I/R       NA             

df_new %>% 
  select(ends_with(".Y")) %>% 
  rename_with(function(x) colnames(counts_df))
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  SampleName V1      V2      
  <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   
1 asd        53      35      
2 asd        66      NA      
3 afsdf      158_100 66_55_30
4 dsg        99      65      
5 eee        64      43      
6 shg        NA      NA      
7 gfdf       181     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest combining the two datasets to make sure that they're aligned before splitting them into the desired frames.

**In one go using `group_split`:**

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

strings_df |>
  pivot_longer(-SampleName, values_to = "string") |>
  left_join(counts_df |> pivot_longer(-SampleName, values_to = "count")) |>
  separate_longer_delim(c(string, count), delim = "_") |>
  reframe(count = sum(as.numeric(count)), .by = c(SampleName, name, string)) |>
  reframe(across(c(string, count), ~ paste(., collapse = "_")), .by = c(SampleName, name)) |>
  pivot_longer(c(string, count), names_to = "split") |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(SampleName, split)) |>
  group_split(split)
```

*Output:*

```
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  SampleName split V1      V2      
  <chr>      <chr> <chr>   <chr>   
1 asd1       count 53      35      
2 asd2       count 66      NA      
3 afsdf      count 158_100 66_55_30
4 dsg        count 99      65      
5 eee        count 64      43      
6 shg        count NA      NA      
7 gfdf       count 181     NA      

[[2]]
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  SampleName split  V1          V2         
  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>       <chr>      
1 asd1       string A/I/R       S/G        
2 asd2       string A/I/R       NA         
3 afsdf      string A/I/R_V/I/R S/G_A/A_C/A
4 dsg        string A/I/R       S/G        
5 eee        string A/I/R       S/G        
6 shg        string NA          NA         
7 gfdf       string A/I/R       NA
```

... Or you could do it a bit more manually ...

**Step 1: The combined data frame:**

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

combined_df <-
  strings_df |>
  pivot_longer(-SampleName, values_to = "string") |>
  left_join(counts_df |> pivot_longer(-SampleName, values_to = "count")) |>
  separate_longer_delim(c(string, count), delim = "_") |>
  reframe(count = sum(as.numeric(count)), .by = c(SampleName, name, string)) |>
  reframe(across(c(string, count), ~ paste(., collapse = "_")), .by = c(SampleName, name))
```

*Output:*

```
   SampleName name  string      count   
   <chr>      <chr> <chr>       <chr>   
 1 asd1       V1    A/I/R       53      
 2 asd1       V2    S/G         35      
 3 asd2       V1    A/I/R       66      
 4 asd2       V2    NA          NA      
 5 afsdf      V1    A/I/R_V/I/R 158_100 
 6 afsdf      V2    S/G_A/A_C/A 66_55_30
 7 dsg        V1    A/I/R       99      
 8 dsg        V2    S/G         65      
 9 eee        V1    A/I/R       64      
10 eee        V2    S/G         43      
11 shg        V1    NA          NA      
12 shg        V2    NA          NA      
13 gfdf       V1    A/I/R       181     
14 gfdf       V2    NA          NA
```

**Step 2: Get the two data frames you want:**

```r
resulting_strings_df <-
  combined_df |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = SampleName, values_from = "string")

resulting_counts_df <-
  combined_df |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = SampleName, values_from = "count")
```

*Output:*

```r
  SampleName V1          V2         
  <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      
1 asd1       A/I/R       S/G        
2 asd2       A/I/R       NA         
3 afsdf      A/I/R_V/I/R S/G_A/A_C/A
4 dsg        A/I/R       S/G        
5 eee        A/I/R       S/G        
6 shg        NA          NA         
7 gfdf       A/I/R       NA
```

```
  SampleName V1      V2      
  <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   
1 asd1       53      35      
2 asd2       66      NA      
3 afsdf      158_100 66_55_30
4 dsg        99      65      
5 eee        64      43      
6 shg        NA      NA      
7 gfdf       181     NA
```

**Assuming that:**

- `samplenames` are unique per now.
- `_` is the separater in `counts_df`
- the number of underscores per `SampleName` doesn't vary across the two dataframes.

**Adjusted data:**

```r
library(readr)

strings_df <- read_table("SampleName  V1  V2
asd1 A/I/R   S/G
asd2 A/I/R   NA
afsdf   A/I/R_A/I/R_V/I/R   S/G_A/A_C/A
dsg A/I/R   S/G
eee A/I/R   S/G
shg NA  NA
gfdf    A/I/R_A/I/R_A/I/R   NA")

counts_df <- read_table("SampleName  V1  V2
asd1 53  35
asd2 66  NA
afsdf   78_80_100   66_55_30
dsg 99  65
eee 64  43
shg NA  NA
gfdf    46_47_88    NA")
```

Comment: got a "could not find function "reframe"" error. is this function from another package not stated?

Comment: It’s the newest version of `dplyr` :-)

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
pivot_longer(strings_df, V1:V2, values_to = 'string') %>%
  left_join(pivot_longer(counts_df, V1:V2)) %>%
  separate_rows(c(string, value),sep = '_', convert = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(value=sum(value), .by=c(SampleName, name, string)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = SampleName, values_from = c(string, value), 
              values_fn = ~str_c(.x, collapse = '_'))


#> # A tibble: 7 × 5
#>   SampleName string_V1   string_V2   value_V1 value_V2
#>   <chr>      <chr>       <chr>       <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 asd1       A/I/R       S/G         53       35      
#> 2 asd2       A/I/R       <NA>        66       <NA>    
#> 3 afsdf      A/I/R_V/I/R S/G_A/A_C/A 158_100  66_55_30
#> 4 dsg        A/I/R       S/G         99       65      
#> 5 eee        A/I/R       S/G         64       43      
#> 6 shg        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>     <NA>    
#> 7 gfdf       A/I/R       <NA>        181      <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: KInda like the simplicity of this code, but I'm getting a "Column `name` doesn't exist." error... Do you know why?

Comment: @hola try running the first two lines of the code and see whether you have a column `name` in the output `pivot_longer(strings_df, V1:V2, values_to = 'string') %>%
  left_join(pivot_longer(counts_df, V1:V2)) %`